# Python Selenium & Browserstack - Connect to proxy

Tags: python, selenium, browserstack

So I am trying to get my browserstack task to use a proxy but I can't seem to get it working. I am running a browserstack local server, setting the arguments via the language bindings and it's just not working. Any help would be much appreciated, I'm not sure what I'm quite doing wrong because I've been following the docs.

It should be connecting to the proxy, however it's not. I have also tried to add some options into the webdriver.Remote function with no luck. There's no errors, but from the screenshot it's capturing it is not using the proxy, not sure why since i am trying to force it in.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from browserstack.local import Local

desired_cap = {
    'bstack:options' : {
        "os" : "Windows",
        "osVersion" : "10",
        "projectName" : "Take Screenshot Sample Test",
        "buildName" : "Take Screenshot Sample Build",
        "local" : "true",
        "seleniumVersion" : "4.0.0",
    },
    "browserstack.local" : "true",
    "browserstack.debug" : "true",
    "browserName" : "Chrome",
    "browserVersion" : "103.0",
    "forceLocal" : "true",
    "forceProxy" : "true",
}
local = Local()
local_args = { "key": "mykey" }
local_args["localproxyHost"] = "myproxyip"
local_args["localproxyPort"] = "8080"
local_args["localproxyUser"] = "user"
local_args["localproxyPass"] = "password"
local_args["forceProxy"] = "true"
local_args["forceLocal"] = "true"
local_args["state"] = "connected"
local_args["tunnelIdentifier"] = "tom"
local_args["localIdentifier"] = "tomjohn"
local.start(**local_args)
driver = webdriver.Remote(
    command_executor='https://myuser:mykey@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',
    desired_capabilities=desired_cap)
driver.get("https://www.whatismyipaddress.com")
driver.save_screenshot('screenshots.png')
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add :

```
"localIdentifier": "tomjohn"
```

inside **bstack:options**.
can you try doing that?

Comment: Hi @Tony_Stark I already tried that with no success.